# How can I add style to the components?

Tags: vue.js

In my `home.vue`, in the template I put several components, they do not have a wrapper to contain them, the code is bellow:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <banner></banner>
    <div class="functions">
      <function-intro></function-intro>
      <function-intro></function-intro>
      <function-intro></function-intro>
      <function-intro></function-intro>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import Banner from './components/banner.vue'
  import FunctionIntro from './components/function-intro.vue'

  export default{

    components: {
      'banner': Banner,
      'function-intro': FunctionIntro   
    }

  }
</script>

<style>

  .home {
    clear:both;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

    min-height: 480px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .functions {

  }

</style>
```

You see I import a FunctionIntro component.

now can I add the style to them?

I can not select them in normal way:

```
.functions function-intro {

}
```

this is wrong.

Comment: It really depends on how `function-intro` is. Show `'./components/function-intro.vue'`; What of it do you want to style?

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the component style in their own `<style>`, and you pass the class in your parent component:

Give you a example.

In you parent component pass the class:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <banner></banner>
    <div class="functions">
      <function-intro :class="'inline-block'"></function-intro>
      <function-intro :class="'inline-block'"></function-intro>
      <function-intro :class="'inline-block'"></function-intro>
      <function-intro :class="'inline-block'"></function-intro>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

in the child component(there is the `FunctionIntro` component) style:

```
.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```